# Slack Bot Interactive Messages

Tags: python, django, bots, slack-api

I'm new at Slack Bot integrations. I want to have buttons on my message, so my code is

```
message = {
        "text": "Would you like to play a game?",
        "attachments": [
            {
                "text": "Choose a game to play",
                "attachment_type": "default",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "chess",
                        "text": "Chess",
                        "type": "button",
                        "value": "chess"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }


return sc.api_call("chat.postMessage",
                    as_user="true",
                    channel=channel_id,
                    text=message)
```

but in Slack channel I see this

```
text=Would+you+like+to+play+a+game%3F&attachments=%5B%7B%27text%27%3A+%27Choose+a+game+to+play%27%2C+%27attachment_type%27%3A+%27default%27%2C+%27actions%27%3A+%5B%7B%27text%27%3A+%27Chess%27%2C+%27type%27%3A+%27button%27%2C+%27name%27%3A+%27chess%27%2C+%27value%27%3A+%27chess%27%7D%5D%7D%5
```

why this happen??

Thanks

Comment: This looks like it might be something related to do with the slack API wrapper you are using. Have you tried doing it by hand using an HTTP call with `requests`? You're message formating also [looks fine.](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22text%22%3A%22Would%20you%20like%20to%20play%20a%20game%3F%22%2C%22attachments%22%3A%5B%7B%22text%22%3A%22Choose%20a%20game%20to%20play%22%2C%22attachment_type%22%3A%22default%22%2C%22actions%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chess%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Chess%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22chess%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D)

Comment: Keep in mind that `chat.postMessage` does not accept JSON post bodies. You need to send your message as `x-www-form-urlencoded` parameters. Additionally, the `attachments` field actually expects JSON, but it must be URL-encoded JSON. A pure JSON message body like this will not work with the Web API.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it myself, but I think you can try doing something like this:

```
message = "Would you like to play a game?"
attachments = [{
                "text": "Choose a game to play",
                "attachment_type": "default",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "chess",
                        "text": "Chess",
                        "type": "button",
                        "value": "chess"
                    }
                ]}]

sc.api_call("chat.postMessage", 
             channel=channel_id, 
             text=message,
             as_user="true",
             attachments=attachments)
```

In case it doesn't work, I would try to include a "title" field in the attachment like this:

```
attachments = [{
                    "title": "new title",
                    ...
```

Comment: a silly question to ask - where to add this scripts for the Slack bot?